# Mocking with Dart - How to test that a function passed as a parameter was called?

Tags: dart

Admittedly, this is a little bit of an odd test case, but it's a problem I've ran in to.  I have a class that takes a function as a parameter in it's constructor.  I'd like to know if the function that was passed was called.  Here's an example:

```dart
class TestClassMock extends Mock implements RealClass {
  RealClass _real;

  TestClassMock() {
    _real = new RealClass();

    when(callsTo("myNamedFunction")).alwaysCall(_real.myNamedFunction);
  }
}

class RealClass {
  String _name = "RealClass";
  Function myNamedFunction;

  RealClass() {
    myNamedFunction = _theNamedFunction;
  }

  String _theNamedFunction() {
    return _name;
  }
}

class ClassThatCallsRealClass {
  ClassThatCallsRealClass(Function func) {
    func();
  }
}

//The test
TestClassMock testClassMock = new TestClassMock();
ClassThatCallsRealClass caller = new ClassThatCallsRealClass(testClassMock.myNamedFunction);  
testClassMock.getLogs(callsTo("myNamedFunction")).verify(happenedOnce);
```

So to explain a bit, ClassThatCallsRealClass takes a function as a parameter and calls it.  If you were to pass in (Instance Of RealClass).myNamedFunction, this would in turn call the private function _theNamedFunction on RealClass.  However, if you try to mock RealClass and redirect all calls from myNamedFunction to the RealClass myNamedFunction, this seems to fail.  I don't see any clear way to get this to work, but I would think it'd be possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Dart, all functions are instances of class `Function` as you know since you pass an instance of `Function` to the `ClassThatCallsRealClass` constructor. Instances of `Function` have a method `call()` as shown [here](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Function.html).

Meanwhile, Dart has a very good mocking capability described [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mockito) (with thanks to @KWalrath for the update).

So all you need to do is test with mocks like with any other object. Just as described in the reference, create a spy for `ClassThatCallsRealClass` and a mock for your `Function` instance. Then use a `verify(happenedOnce)` on the `call()` method of the function.

To mock your function do this:

```
class MockFunction extends Mock {
  call(int a, int b) => a + b;
}

var mock = new MockFunction();
mock(1,2); //returns 3
```

Of course the parameter list to `call` will match that of the real function. Pass `mock` to your spy on `ClassThatCallsRealClass`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by mocking the Function instance.  How would I go about that?

Comment: Edited with something for you to consider.

Comment: The link in the second paragraph is to a very old article that's been removed because it featured an obsolete library. Perhaps look at mockito instead: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mockito

Comment: Yeah, things have changed in the 3.5 years since I wrote that. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Thanks for updating this 3.5 years later!

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me:

```dart
library x;

import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "package:unittest/mock.dart";

class TestClassMock extends Mock implements RealClass {
  RealClass _real;

  TestClassMock() {
    _real = new RealClass();

    when(callsTo("myNamedFunction")).alwaysCall(_real.myNamedFunction);
  }
}

class RealClass {
  String _name = "RealClass";
  Function myNamedFunction;

  RealClass() {
    myNamedFunction = _theNamedFunction;
  }

  String _theNamedFunction() {
    return _name;
  }
}

class ClassThatCallsRealClass {
  ClassThatCallsRealClass(Function func) {
    func();
  }
}

class MyFunc implements Function {

  Function func;
  String functionName;

  MyFunc(this.func, this.functionName);

  call() {
    var inv = new MyInvocation(functionName);
    func(inv);
  }
}

main(List<String> args) {
  test('xx', () {
    //The test
    TestClassMock testClassMock = new TestClassMock();
    ClassThatCallsRealClass caller = new ClassThatCallsRealClass(new MyFunc(testClassMock.noSuchMethod, "myNamedFunction"));  
    testClassMock.getLogs(callsTo("myNamedFunction")).verify(happenedOnce);
  });
}

class MyInvocation extends Invocation {
  final String f;
  MyInvocation(this.f); 

  bool get isGetter => false;

  bool get isMethod => true;

  bool get isSetter => false;

  Symbol get memberName => new Symbol(f);

  Map<Symbol, dynamic> get namedArguments => {};

  List get positionalArguments => [];
}
```

testClassMock.myNamedFunction returns null so I call noSuchMethod directly instead which needs an Invocation.
Invocation is abstract so I created an implemented.
MyFunc is a class that wraps the function. MyFunc can be called as a function because it implements the call method.

Comment: This modifies the method signature of the constructor in ClassThatCallsRealClass, so unfortunately I can't use it.