# Dart Mocking a Function

Tags: dart, dart-unittest

How do I test that a mocked function was called?

I found this example on [Mocking with Dart - How to test that a function passed as a parameter was called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477587/mocking-with-dart-how-to-test-that-a-function-passed-as-a-parameter-was-called) and tried to extend it to check if the function was called.

```dart
library test2;

import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "package:mock/mock.dart";

class MockFunction extends Mock {
  call(int a, int b) => a + b;
}

void main() {
  test("aa", () {

    var mockf = new MockFunction();
    expect(mockf(1, 2), 3);
    mockf.getLogs(callsTo(1, 2)).verify(happenedOnce);
  });
}
```

It appears that the *mockf.getLogs()* structure is empty...

Answer (score 1):

You must mock methods and specify their names in the log. Here's working code:

```dart
library test2;

import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "package:mock/mock.dart";

class MockFunction extends Mock {
  MockFunction(){
    when(callsTo('call')).alwaysCall(this.foo);
  }
  foo(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
    }
}

void main() {
  test("aa", () {    
    var mockf = new MockFunction();
    expect(mockf(1, 2), 3);
    mockf.calls('call', 1, 2).verify(happenedOnce);
  });
}
```

**edit:** 
answer to the similar question: [Dart How to mock a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929619/dart-how-to-mock-a-procedure/23933713#23933713)

Comment: Thanks for that - I now know how to log calls to a method on a mock class. That is a help!  I guess I didn't word my question correctly.  I will raise another question of how to mock a procedure.....